# How to address +HTTPACTION:0,600,0 Not HTTP PDU response

Tags: gsm

I am using the SIM900A gsm module and trying to connect with my site using a GET request. My issue is that when submitting AT+HTTPACTION=0, I receive a status the response as +HTTPACTION:0,600,0. In this case, the GET request is raised successfully but the response size is 0. In this case, I am not able to fetch a response from the server. The datasheet says the 600 code means "Not HTTP PDU" but I am not aware of how I need to address this. I also sometimes receive code 200, but it is very rare.
following is the response of the AT commands:

```
AT

OK
AT+COPS?

+COPS: 0,0,"Vi India"

OK
AT+CGDCONT=1,"IP","internet"

OK
AT+CGDCONT=?

+CGDCONT: (1-3),"IP",,,(0),(0)

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"CONTYPE","GPRS"

OK
AT+SAPBR=3,1,"APN","internet"

OK
AT+SAPBR=1,1

OK
AT+SAPBR=2,1

+SAPBR: 1,1,"100.103.109.188"

OK
AT+HTTPINIT

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="CID",1

OK
AT+HTTPPARA="URL","mysite.co.in/newlist.php?K=THS&a=35.97&b=18.84"

OK
AT+HTTPACTION=0

OK

+HTTPACTION:0,600,0
AT+HTTPTERM

OK
```

Thanks in advance for the support.

**Edit** I have tried further, I have observed that still, the status code still remains the same 0,600,0 status code. However, when I changed the URL to [www.google.com](http://www.google.com), it returns the expected +HTTPACTION:0,200, xxx status code. Please provide some guidance to get the issue resolve.

Comment: How good a signal do you have?

Comment: @Majenko  I just checked AT+CSQ returns +CSQ: 31,0, so I understand, signal strength is good enough